# Change Jsonproperty attributes of inherited class

Tags: c#, json, inheritance, json.net

I have a class `BaseClass`, and some child classes `ChildA` and `ChildB`. I need to apply a `[JsonProperty("someString")]` to a property of the baseClass but the parameter `"someString"` is different for each of the child class.

```cs
public class BaseClass
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ChildA : BaseClass
{
    [JsonProperty("someStringA")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

public class ChildB : BaseClass
{
    [JsonProperty("someStringB")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to archive that?

With the code above i get the following behaviour:

```cs
BaseClass childA = new ChildA()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "aaa",
};

string str = childA.Name;
```

`str` result to be null

Comment: Your Name properties in the subclasses are 'hiding' the base class Name, so you should be seeing [CS0108 compiler warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108). Can you make name `virtual` and override it in the subclasses?

Comment: No, i need that `Name` must be a property of the `baseClass`

Comment: That's not what stuart asks.

Comment: So the question is, how can you have 'Name' property only in the base class, but de/serialize it under different JSON keys depending on the derived class?

Comment: @stuartd I correct myself, you answer seem to work out well.